# Thread is running even when I exit app

Tags: c#, multithreading, httpwebrequest, compact-framework

I'm having a problem with my app with windows embedded (CompactFramework).
I need to connect to internet so I make a dummy request to internet in order to activate the connectivity.

I use this code for that task:

```
WebRequest request = null;
HttpWebResponse response = null;

try
{
    // Create a request for the URL.
    request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com/default.html");

    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    // Get the response.
    request.Timeout = 10000;
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    if ("OK".Equals(response.StatusDescription))
        res = true;
    else { /** Message **/ }

}
catch (WebException) { /*Message*/ }
catch (Exception e) {/*Message*/}
finally 
{
    if (response != null) response.Close();
    if (request != null) request.Abort();
}

try
{
    if (response != null) response.Close();
}
catch (Exception e) { /*Message*/ }

try
{
    if (request != null) request.Abort();
}
catch (Exception e) { /*Message*/ }
```

My problem is that when I exit my app there is some thread that keeps alive. I want to kill all the threads when I exit the app.

When I debug my app and watch the threads I get this info:
[image]

In the picture you can check that the last two threads are thrown by the Start() method. 
When I click the exit button I check again and the two threads are the only that are still alive:
[image]

I don't understand why these threads are alive.

I would like to know how can I avoid this behaviour.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That's odd considering that `ThreadPool` threads are always supposed to be background threads.

Comment: Which version of the compact framework are you using?

Comment: How long did you wait?  DNS lookup timeouts are pretty long.  I'd be curious if they ended cleanly if you waited a minute.

Comment: @tcarvin The background worker thread should still exit when the application ends, right?

Comment: When your application "ends", it could still be hanging around - waiting for the GC to collect it up. I do not now. I find this interesting, though.

Comment: Does is still hang if you remove the mentionned code part ?